# Using a specifing gateway for a packet. (CentOS/RHEL)

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, routing

I have just setup a machine which has two NICs, one for private network and the other one for public network which has a real IP assigned to it.

```
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=XXX
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=XXX
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=172.26.111.131
NETMASK=255.255.255.128
GATEWAY=172.26.111.129
```

Configuration of eth1 for public network as follows;

```
DEVICE=eth1
HWADDR=XXX
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=XXX
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=PUBLIC_IP
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
GATEWAY=PUBLIC_GATEWAY


Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         PUBLIC_GATEWAY   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
PUBLIC_NID      *               255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth1
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1004   0        0 eth1
172.26.111.128  *               255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I am sure this is quite easy to achieve. I have searched about this, but somehow could not get this working. The machine still tries to route private IPs via public gateway.

I would appreciate any ideas on this. Where I am wrong at?

I am just trying to be able to access 172.26.111.128/25 via eth0.

Comment: And what IP address are you coming from?

Comment: which ip you are trying to access in lan provide that also..

Comment: You appear to have given your NIC the network address. That ip isn't valid for a host.

Comment: 172.26.111.131 is the IP address that I want to use for this host on that private network. I am trying to access 172.26.111.130, however, I even cannot ping the gateway itself with this current setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was our fault guys. I was trying to ping a host which indeed does not exist hence I was thinking as if the network was not routing properly. Thanks for all your messages and helps!

Answer (score 0):

#### My setup

I've setup an alias for eth0 so that it actually possesses 2 IP addresses, 192.168.1.6 & 192.168.1.254.

I do something like this locally:

```
ifconfig eth1:0 192.168.1.254
route add -host 192.168.1.254 dev eth1:0
```

This gives me a routing table like this:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
ISP_NETWORK     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         ISP_GATEWAY     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

This gives me a route like this:

```
192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth1
```

#### References

- [Setting up two NICs on two separate LANs provides error](https://serverfault.com/a/178856/2518)

Comment: Hi slm, thank but I indeed am trying to be able to access 172.26.111.128/25 via eth0 while 172.26.111.131(within same network) should be assigned to eth0.

Comment: See my updates.

Comment: Well, to be honest, that did not make much sense to me - 192.168.1.254 ->  0.0.0.0 ? is this reasonable? does not this mean that the stuff destinate that IP will be routed via ISP's gateway?